# Angular2 Component Input Chain

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular2-components

I wanted to make a Angular2 Component chain using Inputs.A simple example chain from app > parent > child . Where in app sets a data which intern is set in child at runtime.Same code below .

```
------------ app.component.ts ---------

import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {ParentComponent} from './parent.component';
@Component({
    selector:'componentchain-tag',
    template: `<h1>Level 0</h1>
    <p><parent-tag [fromapp] = "From Level 0" ></parent-tag>
     `,
    directives: [ParentComponent]
}) 
export class AppComponent {
fromapp: string;
}
```

------------- parent.component.ts ----------------

```
import {Component,Input} from 'angular2/core';
import {Child1Component} from './child1.component';
@Component({
    selector:'parent-tag',
    template: `<h1>Level 1</h1>
    <p><child1-tag [child1value] = {{fromapp}} ></child1-tag>
     `,
    directives: [Child1Component]
}) 
export class ParentComponent {
     @Input() fromapp: string;
    child1value: string;
    constructor(){
    }
}
```

--------------------------- child1.component.ts ---------

```
import {Component,Input} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'child1-tag',
    template: `<h1>Level 3-1</h1>
    This is Child1
    <p>This is variable from {{child1value}}
    `
})
export class Child1Component {
    @Input() child1value: string;

}
```

In parent.component.ts tried playing around with `{{fromapp}}`, like saving in temp variable and so on but it does not work. I get error saying in `parent.component` `fromapp` is not defined.

How to do multi-chaining of components, its basics right?

Comment: one more update {{fromapp}} cannot be pass unless we create a customized derivative. Not much literature is available on this.

Answer (score 0):

This is invalid

```
<p><child1-tag [child1value] = {{fromapp}} ></child1-tag>
```

it should be

```
<p><child1-tag [child1value]="fromapp"></child1-tag>
```

- `{{}}` stringifies the value
- `{{}}` can't be combined with `[]`, `()`, or *xxx (like `*ngFor`)

Comment: Thanks @günter-zöchbauer, That works. To add to this, if I have 2nd child component. How to pass two values from app which will be received by respective childs. So inside app.component.ts somethig like this <parent-tag [fromappforchild1,fromappforchild2] = {"From Level 0-Child1","FromLevel 0-Child2"} ></parent-tag>

Comment: The `<parent-tag` confuses me a bit. You pass data from parent to child using bindings. This would look like <child-tag [inputInChild1]="propertyInParent1" [inputInChild2]="propertyInParent2"></child-tag>`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way to solve it

```
  <parent-tag fromappforchild1 = "From Level 0-Child1" fromappforchild2 = "FromLevel 0-Child2" ></parent-tag>
```

Detail document here

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/Input-var.html

Still not clear what doing inside parent-tag , how to control. For example in my app.component.ts if I have templevel0 = "test" , I cannot put it inside parent-tag at all..